# Display item in Android Listview item and its information

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I am developing and android app which deals with records display of students which contains the data of the students in `mysql` `phpmyadmin` . **The details of the Students are (Name, Roll Number , Age , Gender , Mobile Number etc. ) are stored in phpmyadmin database** .

Now I have created a `ListView` in my app which displays the name of every student which is stored in the database . 
There are two type of students who are currently working on project and some who are not working .
 So my question is that Now i want to display **only student names who are working on a project** in my `ListView` which i have created . So in brief The user database contains all the students but the listview must only fetch the students who are working on a project .
 I thought to do by assigning boolean value **like 1 to working students and 0 to non working students in phpmyadmin** and then show the ones with boolean value 1 in the `ListView` , but couldnt execute it .
So please tell me the appropriate way to do it .
 It will be great of you if I can get some sample code. Its very important for me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i think you should give us your code first, then we can help you to fix it.

for the object student, i think it will be better to put the student role in a separate table.

i think you're doing the right thing, by using the booalean value.

it will be something like :

```
SELECT data
FROM Table_Name
WHERE property='1';
```

Comment: Thanks , i tried and it worked , just added a column of status in the database and used the above query in php . Android was not used anywhere .